# Class visualization tools for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, code-visualization

Does anyone know of any static class/code explorer/visualisation tools for Objective-C? Something to help become familiar with large code-bases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/)

You can drop an Xcode project file onto it and it will create a class diagram for you.

Comment: +1 holy cow, it can do that?? */me goes off and checks* DANG SON.

Comment: @Dave DeLong - Hate to tell you this - but it's been able to do this since Xcode3. Though it doesn't seem to work as well as it used to.

Comment: O.o Did not know this

Answer (score 2):

Few of options I've come across:

1. Scitools:  https://scitools.com/index.php

   Pros: Lots of features and some interesting plugins
   Cons: $1000 (15 day free trial)
2. Combination of Graphviz (similar to OmniGraffle but free) and NST's objc_dep project (converts objective-c files into Graphviz readable file): http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php and https://github.com/nst/objc_dep

   Pros: Free
   Cons: Not so many features

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 3 and 4 differ feature-wise in this regard.

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) offers some cool advanced features (interactive browsing, graphs). it also works well with other languages. probably the most featured/detailed, but not integrated with the sources like an ide.

lastly, check out [JetBrains' AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/). although it's still in it's infancy as an ide for objc, what they have done for Java has been great.

Comment: Heh, someone has reached 10K. Congratulations!